# PostgreSQL - Setting null values to missing rows in a join statement

Tags: postgresql

SQL newbie here. I'm trying to write a query that generates a scoring table, setting null to a student's grades in a module for which they haven't yet taken their exams (on PostgreSQL).

So I start with tables that look something like this:

```
student_evaluation:
|student_id| module_id | course_id |grade  | 
|----------|-----------|-----------|-------| 
| 1        | 1         |     1     |3      |
| 1        | 1         |     1     |7      | 
| 1        | 2         |     1     |8      | 
| 2        | 4         |     2     |9      | 

course_module: 
| module_id  | course_id |
| ---------- | --------- |
| 1          | 1         |
| 2          | 1         |
| 3          | 1         |
| 4          | 2         |
```

In our use case, a course is made up of several modules. Each module has a single exam, but a student who failed his exam may have a couple of retries. The same module may also be present in different courses, but an exam attempt only counts for one instance of the module (ie. student A passed module 1's exam on course 1. If course 2 also has module 1, student A has to retake the same exam for course 2 if he also has access to that course).

So the output should look like this:

| student_id | module_id | course_id | grade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 7 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 8 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | null |
| 2 | 4 | 2 | 9 |

I feel like this should have been a simple task, but I think I have a very flawed understanding of how outer and cross joins work. I have tried stuff like:

```
SELECT se.student_id, se.module_id, se.course_id, se.grade FROM student_evaluation se
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN course_module ON course_module.course_id = se.course_id 
    AND course_module.module_id = se.module_id
```

or

```
SELECT se.student_id, se.module_id, se.course_id, se.grade FROM student_evaluation se
  CROSS JOIN course_module WHERE course_module.course_id = se.course_id
```

Neither worked. These all feel wrong, but I'm lost as to what would be the proper way to go about this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need both join types: first use a cross join to build a list of all combinations of students and courses, then use an outer join to add the grades.

```
SELECT sc.student_id,
       sc.module_id,
       sc.course_id,
       se.grade
FROM student_evaluation se
   RIGHT JOIN (SELECT s.student_id,
                      c.module_id,
                      c.course_id
               FROM (SELECT DISTINCT student_id
                     FROM student_evaluation) AS s
                  CROSS JOIN course_module AS c) AS sc
      USING (course_id));
```